# Sitecore document field is null after building the index

Tags: indexing, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore8

I am facing a problem, after publishing the web in sitecore then building the sitecore_web_index the items are indexed but with document filed value of null!

I am working on Sitecore 8.1 on windows 10

[image]

using luke to see whats going on 
[image]

any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the storage type on the index for those fields. By default a lot of the fields in the Lucene indexes are set to `storageType="NO"` - this will index the field content but not store the data in the index, so the fields will always appear empty in the results.

Example config from `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config`:

```
<fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldTypeName">
    <fieldType fieldTypeName="attachment" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
    <!-- omitted for brevity -->
</fieldTypes>
```

If you *need* to see the field contents in the results, set `storageType="YES"` for the require field types in the config. Note tho that this will increase the size of your index.

Comment: @Richard Seal, is this necessary? I mean if I keep storageType as 'No', will I still be able to search on this field, since all fields are 'No' by default and search usually works?

Comment: if the storageType is `No` - searching will still work. The field is still tokenized in the index and searchable. *BUT* - you will not be able to retrieve the value of the field from the index, you will have to go to the Sitecore item to get the value.